# ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero; python scipy quad

Tags: python, scipy, sympy, numerical-integration, quad

I am writing a program that use integrals. I tried Sympy, but it was too slow, so I switched to SciPy integrate and it's improve my script so much, but I encountered one problem:

In general, it like this:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import sympy as S

x = S.Symbol('x')
y = S.Symbol('y')
xi = 0.75
a = 10; b = 10; f1 = 0.5; f2 = 0.5; f0 = f1+f2; al = -f1/f0; be = -f2/f0 `
F0 = f0*(al*(x**2/a**2)*xi+be*(y*2/b**2)**xi+1)
j2 = F0.diff(y,2)
jj2 = S.lambdify([y],j2,'scipy')
J2_ = quad(jj2,-a,a)
J2 = (J2_[0]*a**2)/f0
```

and it just crushed and here is error:

```
File "C:\Users\Mikhail\Desktop\robpy\cyc.py", line 60, in raschet
J2_ = quad(jj2,-a,a)
File "C:\Users\Mikhail\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_quadpack_py.py", line 463, in quad
retval = _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit,
File "C:\Users\Mikhail\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_quadpack_py.py", line 575, in _quad
return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
File "<lambdifygenerated-2>", line 2, in _lambdifygenerated
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

F0.diff(y,2) equal to:
`-0.0118585412256314*(y**2)0.75/y**2`

I suggest that this "y2" in denominator is the cause of the error, but when I've tried SymPy to do same integration like

`jj2 = S.integrate(j2,(y,-a,a))`

it works normal and solve it as -0.15

I can't just rebuild F0 using floats instead of variables cause task suppose different initial data from user.

How can I avoid this error? Thank you.

Comment: Is there any way that it's rounding down to 0 before the division occurs? It's definitely trying to divide by 0. What is the denominator right before the division?

Comment: For me, `print(F0.diff(y,2))` equals `0.00498590240338593/y**1.25`. This is an improper integral which is undefined at 0.

Comment: The `help(jj2)` show that it returns `return 0.00498590240338593*y**(-1.25)`.  `jj2(0)` raises `ZeroDivisionError: 0.0 cannot be raised to a negative power`.  `quad` must be trying to evaluate the function at 0, which is to be expected given a -10,10 range.

Comment: `S.integrate(j2,(y,-a,a))` gives me a complex value.  `j2` for negative values is complex.

Comment: @hpaulj, as you can see, this function suppose that F0 always will be in (-a,a) range, so it is always will be 0 in this range. Anyway, sympy can solve this, and return negative float, so I think I should make something in `quad` that forced to avoid 0 when integrating it. Can I do this avoiding using `lambdify`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all for your help!
I solve that problem like this

```
def jj2(x,y):
    if y == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return j2(y)
J2_ = quad(jj2,-a,a)
J2 = (J2_[0]*a**2)/f0
```

So it return complex, but F0 is just one part of integral that I need, so it solving and solving right!

(yay, I reduced the execution time from 240 seconds to 3 sec!)